# How do I use PowerShell to remove registry keys from a remote computer?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell to remove profiles and associated registry entries on remote computers. The account I am using has administrator permissions on the remote computers. I have no trouble pulling the SIDs of the accounts or deleting the profile. My problem comes when trying to remove the registry key for the account located at HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\'Windows NT'\CurrentVersion\ProfileList. There is a key for every SID and I want to remove the ones that match the profiles I am deleting.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Enter-PSSession $comp
Remove-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\'Windows NT'\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$SID"
Exit-PSSession
```

This got the following result:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\'Windows 
NT'\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1000' because it does not exist.
```

If I run the same command on the local machine, the key is deleted successfully.

I also tried:

```
Enter-PSSession $comp
Remove-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' -name $SID
Exit-PSSession
```

Which returned the following:

```
Remove-Itemproperty : Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

I have also tried using invoke-command to run the exact same command that works locally and I get the same error.

Is there something I am missing? Can any of you kind folks point out what I am doing wrong? I would really like to do this with built-in commands rather than installing a third party module if possible.

Comment: Are you running this as an Administrator?

Comment: To clarify, the account I am using is a domain account with admin rights on the remote computers.

Comment: You still need your PSSession to be running As Administrator.

Comment: You might also want to look at the .NET namespace Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey - this will allow you to manipulate a remote registry without using PowerShell remoting - however, the remote computer will need to have the Remote Registry service running.

Comment: I recommend using [delprof2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) rather than trying to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to remove user profiles and cannot use a third party tool I would recommend using the CIM classes.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID = 'S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1000'" -ComputerName $comp | Remove-CIMInstance -WhatIf
```

If you do not have winrm enabled or configured you can fallback on WMI.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_UserProfile -Filter "SID = 'S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-1000'" -ComputerName $comp | Remove-WmiObject -WhatIf
```

This will get not only the registry key but also the folders associated with the profile.

Comment: Thank you! The WMI method did exactly what I was looking for.